# How to get camera specification in android programmatically?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I want to get the specification of the Camera like below picture in my android app. How can I get it?

Sample from CPU-X:
[image: Sample from CPU-X]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Camera API class' Camera.getParameters() provided by google which will return the intended details which you require.
If your device uses Android 9 and above, you need to use Camera.getCameraInfo() method.
Learn about both of these methods here.

[Check Camera Features](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#check-camera-features)